# Does the sign on a non-significant IV coefficient matter?

Tags: regression-coefficients

I have a logistic regression where I am forcing some IVs into the model. I am getting the "wrong sign" i.e. contrary to what is expected, but the association is not significant. Does the sign matter when the IV is not-significant (I can live with it being not significant)? And does the magnitude of the coefficient matter when the association is not significant?

Comment: Two things are both true. (1) If the coefficient is really close to zero, its sign is immaterial. (2) It's nicer if the signs make sense. The decision when these conflict is hard to generalise about. For example, the "wrong" sign might be a side-effect of overall nonlinearity or of collinearity between predictors. Non-significance might just mean that you really need a larger sample.

Comment: Unexepected results can often occur in statistical models when you begin to control for other variables.